# How to bulk convert numbers to text in Excel without formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

I have imported tabular data into Excel and it interpreted long sequnces of figures as numbers and displayed them in scientific form:

[image]

How to tell this thing, that these are text? In previous version of Excel it was possible to format cells as text and then paste as values into the same place. In modern Excel I have formatted cells as text, but this thing still displays it in scientific form.

How to overcome?

Comment: How are you importing this data? If you are simply opening a CSV file by double-clicking, try renaming it to have .txt extension which will prompt Excel to use the data import wizard rather than guessing. In that wizard you can specify this column as text. Alternatively, use Power Query to pull the data in, which is more repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

No sure about excel 2016 but I usually select the cells and press CTRL-1, 'special -> zip code.

Comment: Why use ZIP code?

Answer (score 1):

Select the errant cells, and then *Data > Data Tools > Text to Columns* on the ribbon.

Click `Next` twice to get to step 3 of 3. In the *Column Data format* options, select `Text`. Click `Finish` and your cells should be properly formatted as text.

When you paste into Excel from another application, a small tag appears from which you can select `Use Text Import Wizard...` which gets you started on the above.

This is based on Excel 2013 but I guess it's similar in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click > `Format Cells` > `Number` Tab > `Custom` > Type in (or choose) 0.

[image]